# Animate the canvas object

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I made a constructor function which contains two functions. one of them `update()`, in the `update function` there are two conditions which should update the `this.dx` or `this.dy` value but they are not updating the value.

Here is the JS Fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/c9gnub14/

But when I use the same conditions outside of the constructor (inside `animate()` function) it is working: https://jsfiddle.net/b8h6j1vn/1/

Actually, I want to animate my canvas object, can you tell me what's wrong with this code?

Here is the JS Fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/c9gnub14/
check this snippet please:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
  c = canvas.getContext('2d')

canvas.width = window.innerWidth
canvas.height = window.innerHeight

function Circle(x, y, dx, dy, radius) {
  this.x = x
  this.y = y
  this.dx = dx
  this.dy = dy
  this.radius = radius

  this.draw = function() {
    c.beginPath()
    c.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false)
    c.strokeStyle = 'blue'
    c.stroke()
  }

  this.update = function() {
    // ######################
    // dx & dy value is not updating with this code

    if (this.x + this.radius > innerWidth || this.x - this.radius < 0) {
      this.dx = -this.dx
      console.log('dx is ' + this.dx)
    }
    if (this.y + this.radius > innerHeight || this.y - this.radius < 0) {
      this.dy = -this.dy
      console.log('dy is ' + this.dx)
    }

    this.x += this.dx
    this.y += this.dy
    this.draw()
  }
}

var x = 200,
  y = 200,
  dx = 3,
  dy = 3,
  radius = 30

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate)
  c.clearRect(0, 0, innerWidth, innerHeight)
  var circle = new Circle(x, y, dx, dy, radius)
  circle.update()

  // if (x + radius > innerWidth || x - radius < 0) {
  //     dx = -dx
  // }
  // if (y + radius > innerHeight || y - radius < 0) {
  //     dy = -dy
  // }

  // x += dx
  // y += dy
}

animate()
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: "Constructor function is not going to update object value" Please post your questions so that it is clear what your problem is

Comment: I'm not clear what you've said, can you please explain?

Answer (score 0):

> the update function should update the this.dx or this.dy value but it is not updating the value,

Based on the logic you've written, it would update those values *only* if the circle is off screen. But it isn't off-screen. The center point is 200,200 and the radius is 30, so it spans from 170 to 230, which is already on-screen, and therefore neither dx nor dy will change.

Comment: I just disable the condition inside the `this.update` & use the same condition outside of the constructor, now animation is working. check please: https://jsfiddle.net/b8h6j1vn/

Answer (score 0):

> Just call this variable outside of the animate function 
>   `var circle = new Circle(x, y, dx, dy, radius)`

You've called `constructor function` inside `animate function` every time `animate function` removing your old circle and creating a new one with your predefined `x, y, dx, dy and radius` value.